# How to convert HTML, CSS, Javascript code into WordPress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I wrote the following code for a page in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  How do I transform this into a WordPress Page Template?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css/global.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="box1">
    <div class="top1"></div>
        <!-- Content Start Here -->
        <div id="m-container">
            <h1>Featured Clients &amp; Partners</h1>
            <ul class="filterClients" style="float:left; clear:both; margin:0 0 0 0px; ">
                <li><a href="#" class="it">IT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Content Start Here --> 
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I see a missing close-tag `</div>`.  Questions are better when they show a little context and research, e.g. [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/page-templates/).

Comment: My Question was how i can add this page to the WordPress. Or How i can create or Convert it into the WordPress template page. If i have to Convert it.

Comment: If you haven't already, you may want to take a look at the [wordpress stack exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).  Although a [related question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42542/html-to-wordpress-plugin) there didn't do so well.  [Another](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83855/how-to-load-javascript-on-custom-page-template) is more about javascript.

Answer (score 1):

For creating Wp template check below code & save your template file name inside theme directory.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Custom Template */
get_header();
?>

    <div class="box1">
        <div class="top1"></div>
            <!-- Content Start Here -->
            <div id="m-container">
                <h1>Featured Clients &amp; Partners</h1>
                <ul class="filterClients" style="float:left; clear:both; margin:0 0 0 0px; ">
                    <li><a href="#" class="it">IT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Content Start Here --> 
        </div>  



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new .php file in your WordPress theme folder, add the following code on the first line:

```
<?php
//* Template Name: Example */
?>
```

Followed by your own code.

Return to the WordPress admin area, create a new page and assign the template via the Template dropdown.

You can then amend your template file to pull in the usual WordPress fields, title, content etc.